# NoClassDefFoundError in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rfid

I am using Impinj speedway  connecter to connect RFID tag reader;

if I am using simple core java program I will work and run this program with external jars  of octane SDK jar  in classpath

but I when i convert this program to spring boot application it will not able to read the impinjReader class from jar 
impinjReader= new ImpinjReader();

and it keeps giving me NoClassDefFoundError

***Spring boApplicationion***

```
package com.Amazin.Tag.Reader;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.impinj.octane.ImpinjReader;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TagReaderApplication implements CommandLineRunner {


    ImpinjReader impinjReader;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TagReaderApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("reading imping reader");

        impinjReader= new ImpinjReader();


    }

}
```

***POM.xml file***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.Amazin.Tag.Reader</groupId>
    <artifactId>Tag_Reader</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Tag_Reader</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.octane</groupId>
            <artifactId>OctaneSDKJava</artifactId>
            <version>1.28.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.llrp</groupId>
            <artifactId>ltkjava</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

***Error Message***

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/mina/core/RuntimeIoException
    at com.Amazin.Tag.Reader.TagReaderApplication.run(TagReaderApplication.java:25) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:797) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.Amazin.Tag.Reader.TagReaderApplication.main(TagReaderApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mina.core.RuntimeIoException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
```

Comment: For 1.28.0.1, Java libraries require Java 1.7 or newer. Did you setup your ide as mentioned here: https://support.impinj.com/hc/en-us/articles/219015497-Setting-up-Octane-SDK-Java-with-Eclipse

Comment: yes i am using java 8

Comment: can you check whether OctaneSDKJava.jar file is added in your build path.

Comment: dependency `<groupId>com.octane</groupId>
            <artifactId>OctaneSDKJava</artifactId>
            <version>1.28.0.1</version>` is not available @maven central, make sure you add repository url so that it can fetch from there and add it to your project.

Comment: I added jar in the folder manually  and they able to read it

Comment: If you are using eclipse: I would suggest to follow their SDK setup for eclipse. Manually adding jar is fine, but it will not package as part of your project.

Comment: i am like those  packages